# How to use grep in NSIS 2.44

Tags: string, command-line, grep, nsis

Is there any easy way to use grep functionality in NSIS scripts?

I have found the link stating a grep.exe tool, but ... umm ... I have no clue how to get it and if it is not just waste of time ..

Link: http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=142028

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can call command line tools from NSIS, but what are you trying to accomplish? Maybe that grep is not the best way to do it.

FWIW, you can [manipulate text files](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Category%3aText_Files_Manipulation_Functions) directly from NSIS.

Comment: oH, THANKS, i RE-SEARCHED THE TOPICS AND FOUND THE THING i NEEDED mUCH APPRECIATED!